# Qt - linking an external static lib that uses WinBase

Tags: windows, qt, linker

I'm trying to build a GUI using Qt 5.3.1 and having that link to a static lib (built with VisualStudio 2010 using /MD and /MDd). When linking in QtCreator IDE, I get 2 unresolved external linker errors generated from these two function calls from within the static lib.

Both of these (unresolved) functions are declared in WinBase.h.

```
::InitializeSecurityDescriptor
::SetSecurityDescriptorDacl
```

What is the easiest solution to get QtCreator to compile this lib? Ideally if possible, I'd like to also link whatever dependency in the static lib itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation of [both](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379583.aspx) [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378863.aspx) specifies, you have to link against advapi32.lib. In general, all functions of the Windows SDK specify in a box at the end of the documentation the header where they are declared, the header that you should actually include and their import library.

As for the other dependencies, AFAIK there's no way to know - static libraries are just collections of object modules, that specify their dependencies only in terms of imported functions.